# Android: Override own XML View in XML

Tags: android, xml, styles, overriding

I am looking for a way to override my own XML view in android.
So I only have to specify settings (like background, border, default content) once - and use it again.

The problem is that I can't find anything about it.
(The things I found are about using a java class in XML to override, this is not what I want)

This is some non-working code, but I hope it explains it well enough to you:

```
main.xml:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <field android:text="@string/str1" />
    <field android:text="@string/str2" />
    <field android:text="@string/str3" />
    <field android:text="@string/str4" />
    <field android:text="@string/str5" />
</LinearLayout>

code representing field (field.xml):
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/field"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/field_background"
    android:text="@string/default_string"/>
```

As you see field itself is once defined and used many times with one customization. (Another string as text set)

This doesn't work at all, but I hope someone knows a way to make something like this work. (Without coding, just XML)

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you set up a style. In some file (usually `styles.xml`) in `res/values`, add a style for your field:

```
<style name="DefaultTextFieldStyle">
    <item name="android:id">@+id/field</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@layout/field_background</item>
</style>
```

Then in `main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView style="@style/DefaultTextFieldStyle"
        android:text="@string/str1" />
    <TextView style="@style/DefaultTextFieldStyle"
        android:text="@string/str2" />
    <TextView style="@style/DefaultTextFieldStyle"
        android:text="@string/str3" />
    <TextView style="@style/DefaultTextFieldStyle"
        android:text="@string/str4" />
    <TextView style="@style/DefaultTextFieldStyle"
        android:text="@string/str5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I just copied your values, but it's wrong to have the same `android:id` value for several views in a layout and it's weird to have a layout as a background.

Comment: I don't think the compiler'll let you define `android:id` inside a Style, anyway the idea is correct and I agree with it. I would also add style's parent, so that 'common' TextField behaviour is garanteed.

Comment: @Shine - I just tried defining a style containing an `<item name="android:id">@+id/foo</item>` and both the compiler and Android Lint were perfectly happy with it. I didn't test whether the id value would actually be applied to a view, but I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: Because, as you said, it's wrong to have the same android:id value for several views..I think it's a "conceptual" error but nevermind :)

Comment: Styles did the job. :)

The android:id I set in the "parent" TextView was because I thought the children nodes should identify it with that. (But apparently not)

However, many thanks for this solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do what you want without code .. I would define my own [custom component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html). Also see [Different formats for different Textview defined by Custom style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761508/different-formats-for-different-textview-defined-by-custom-style) which shows how to style TextViews which could be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

No need for custom components here. If I understood your question, styles should be enough to do what are you looking for.

Just define A serie of TextViews inside the LinearLayout, and let them inheritate the common parts (`layout_width`, `layout_height`, etc.) from a Style you can define as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html).

The only changing part will be `android:text`, as required