# Applying style to views dynamically in java code

Tags: android, styles, custom-component

I have following custom button view.

```
public class PrayerTimeLabel extends Button {

int hours;
int minutes;
String dayHalf; //am or pm
Context parentActivity;
PrayerControl parentControl;

public PrayerTimeLabel(Context context,PrayerControl parent) {
    super(context);                 
    init(context,parent,0);
}

public PrayerTimeLabel(Context context, int defStyle, PrayerControl parent) {
    //super(context, null, R.style.Button_PrayerTimeButton);
    super(context, null, defStyle);             
    init(context,parent,defStyle);
}


private void init(final Context context, PrayerControl parent, int defStyle)
{        
    parentActivity = context;
    parentControl = parent;
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/digital.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(tf);       
    this.setText(false);

    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimeDialog dialogBox = parentControl.getDialogBox();
            dialogBox.setTime(hours, minutes, dayHalf);
            dialogBox.show();
        }
    });
}


public void setTime(int hrs, int min, String half,boolean signalParent)
{
    hours = hrs;
    minutes = min;
    dayHalf = half;
    this.setText(signalParent);
}

public void setText(boolean signalParent)
{
    super.setText(String.format("%02d", hours)+":"+String.format("%02d", minutes)+" "+dayHalf);
    if(signalParent){
        parentControl.setPrayerTime(hours, minutes, dayHalf);
    }
}

}
```

and I have the following style defined in my style.xml

```
    <style name="Button.PrayerTimeButton" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF00</item>
</style>
```

The extended button is not getting this style. Can some on point our what I am doing wrong? I searched for the solution and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=12683). Can some one suggest some thing

Note: I cannot use XML to apply styles. It has to be constructor.

Edit:

Following is the class where this custom button is created and used. I have deleted many irrelevant lines of code

```
public class PrayerControl extends LinearLayout {


protected PrayerTimeLabel prayerTimeButton;

protected String prayerName;
protected static int counter=0;


public PrayerControl(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public PrayerControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    getXMLAttributes(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

    protected void getXMLAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.PrayerControl);

    prayerName = a.getString(R.styleable.PrayerControl_name);
    dayHalf = a.getString(R.styleable.PrayerControl_dayHalf);
    hours = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PrayerControl_hours, 4);
    minutes = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PrayerControl_minutes, 30);

    ltrProgress = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PrayerControl_postNamazInterval, 0);
    rtlProgress = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PrayerControl_preNamazInterval, 0);
    intervalMax = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PrayerControl_intervalMax, 30);


    a.recycle();

}

protected void init(Context context)
{
    counter++;
    parentActivity = context;
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    this.setId(counter);    

    prayerTimeButtonStyle = R.style.Button_PrayerTimeButton;
    initializePrayerTimeButton();

}


protected void initializePrayerTimeButton()
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            40);        
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    //params.weight  = 1.0f;

    prayerTimeButton = new PrayerTimeLabel(parentActivity,prayerTimeButtonStyle,this);
    prayerTimeButton.setTime(hours, minutes, dayHalf,false);

    prayerTimeButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.addView(prayerTimeButton);
}

}
```

Comment: What does getxmlAttributes do?

Comment: i have updated the code to include that function. It just reads value of items in attr.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old answer: I got a -1 a couple of minutes ago and here is the

***NEW SOLUTION***:

The basic idea is to pass an attribute to the constructor.
Check this link for the complete solution: [Applying style to views dynamically in java code](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/12/applying-style-to-views-dynamically-in.html)

***OLD SOLUTION (NOT WORKING)***:

Add these constructors to your class:

```
public StyledButton(Context context) {
    super(context, null, R.style.Button_PrayerTimeButton);
//... whatever
}

public StyledButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, R.style.Button_PrayerTimeButton);
//... whatever
}

public StyledButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, R.style.Button_PrayerTimeButton);
//... whatever
}
```

Comment: I added these constructors but no use :(

Comment: +1 on the previous comment, this does not work for me either.

Comment: @adstro thanks for the -1, I just saw this and the updated the answer

Comment: @sadaf please check the updated answer in case you still maybe need this

Comment: Thanks, this is the only way I could find to style a programmatically created TabLayout without resorting to reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `setTextAppearance(Context context, int resid);`. It lets you set the text color, size, style, hint color, and highlight color.

In `PrayerTimeLabel` class,

```
private void init(final Context context, PrayerControl parent, int defStyle)
{        
    setTextAppearance(context, R.style.Button_PrayerTimeButton);
    ...
}
```

For more info see this post : [setTextAppearance through code referencing custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757764/settextappearance-through-code-referencing-custom-attribute)

Comment: Its not just textView, textview is the simplest of all that is why I have pasted the code for textview. I have other custom controls that inherit from SeekBar and other android controls. I am having issues setting the styles for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an old answer (and simpler) for this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21455192/4360308

Summarizing:

ContextThemeWrapper newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(baseContext, R.style.MyStyle);
button = new Button(newContext);

Answer (score 0):

You should make in your constructor a call to the `super(context,attrs,defStyle)` constructor, which will apply the `defStyle` to your `View`.

However you can not than change the `style` dinamically.

Comment: I am doing it in the following line

    super(context, null, R.style.Button_PrayerTimeButton);

in second constructor. Can you please point out what is wrong with this code?

Comment: can I also see the code where you add those custom views to a layout?

Comment: Actually, this custom button is part of another custom control which is then added to the layout. That is why i want to apply styles using constructor and not using XML. Let me update the question to add code there...

Answer (score 0):

The bug report you link to states:

> In addition, when dynamically creating elements at run-time this means that you can't simply apply a style in code.  You need to create a separate XML layout for the view you're building, and inflate it [...]

With this in mind, a solution could look like this:

Create an xml layout for your button - let's call it prayertimebutton.xml:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        //...etc
/>
```

Then, in the `initializePrayerTimeButton` method in your `PrayerControl` class, inflate and add the `PrayerTimeLabel` button to the `PrayerControl` layout:

```
//Retrieve a LayoutInflater instance that is hooked up to the current context
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//The LayoutInflater instantiates the layout file into a PrayerTimeLabel object
PrayerTimeLabel button = (PrayerTimeLabel)inflater.inflate(R.layout.prayertimebutton, this, false);
//add the PrayerTimeLabel to the PrayerControl
this.addView(button);
```

Note that the second parameter of `LayoutInflater.inflate()` is a reference to the parent View(Group).

The below answer by adamp, an Android framework engineer at Google, discusses this approach in more detail.

[Why so complex to set style from code in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369504/why-so-complex-to-set-style-from-code-in-android)

Comment: Yes, I read that but I don't want to use XML layout files. It has to be done using constructors. This issue was reported in 2010, I am surprised that there is no updates to this issue..

Comment: May I ask why you have to use constructors? My understanding was you need to instantiate the button dynamically with its own style and add it dynamically to a layout, which the solution in my answer makes possible. From the bug report it appears using constructors to pass the style is a dead end. It is indeed surprising there are no updated to this.

Comment: because I have about 15 custom controls and inflating so many XML files is not good in terms of resources so i was thinking may be some one has found a solution for this issue but it seems i was wrong :(